# Multi-threaded race condition issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, race-condition, c++17

I am having a bit of multi-threading issues with some of my code. The `ManagedObject` class implements "lazy-initialization", which uses the `Initialize` method to initialize its state. Every accessor calls `Initialize`. This is because the initialization can be quite costly for the performance.

Now in a single threaded environment my implementation below has no issues, but in my current situation it can be accessed from multiple threads, so they can both start the Initialization process at the same time.

It gets invalidated 60-100 times a second and does the initialization process again when some other thread tries to access data from the managed object. Because multiple threads can ask for data on the same object the initialization can overlap and mess things up badly.

Would really appreciate if someone could point me  at some best practises here!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

class ManagedObject
{
protected:
    std::atomic<bool> initialized = false;

public:
    void Initialize(std::string name)
    {
        if (initialized) return;

        // this code should only be ran once. Since initialized can still be false, other threads may start initializing as well, this should not happen.
        Sleep(500);
        cout << name << ": Initializing 1" << endl << endl;
        Sleep(500);

        initialized = true;
    }

    void Invalidate()
    {
        initialized = false;
    }

    bool IsActive(std::string name)
    {
        Initialize(name);
        return true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto object1 = make_shared<ManagedObject>();

    std::thread([&] {
        object1->IsActive("Thread 1");
    }).detach();

    std::thread([&] {
        object1->IsActive("Thread 2");
    }).detach();

    Sleep(5000);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
Thread 1: Initializing 1

Thread 2: Initializing 1
```

The expected output should be only **one** thread initializing, while the other waits for the initialized state without doing the initialization process itself.

Comment: Why did you expect only one thread initializing when you set `initialized = true` only **after** printing `Initializing 1`?

Comment: @VTT I know this code won't work properly in a multi-threaded way, I would like to know how this would be properly solved. I am currently reading about `std::call_once` which may help me out. Because there are way more experienced people on SO I would like to know best practices on this case.

Comment: Look at compare_exchange_XXX and use one: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange  to check/set your flag.

Comment: The standard way that first comes to mind is to use a lock (`std::mutex`).

Comment: Why not initialize this object in the main thread (actually in constructor) when creating and then pass to threads?

Comment: @VTT It gets invalidated 60-100 times a second and does the initialization process again when some other thread tries to access data from the managed object. Because multiple threads can ask for data on the same object the initialization can overlap and mess things up badly.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I am not sure if a mutex will help here, since it will block the execution, not prevent it. The `Initialize()` method should only be ran when `initialized = false`.

Comment: Then perhaps you are looking for `static` - local static initialization is thread safe in C++11 and above (google "C++ magic static").

Comment: Look up a tutorial, a book, or a presentation about multi-threaded coding. Preventing races is simple (either don't share data, or put a big lock around any code that accesses that data). Doing it in an efficient manner not so much, but it seems to me as if you are missing some basics

Comment: For this particular problem you can e.g. just protect the whole function body of initialize as-is by a mutex.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a classic race condition to me. Can easily be solved by using a mutex within `IsActive()` or `Initialize()`.

Like so

```
bool IsActive(std::string name)
{
    initMutex.lock();
    Initialize(name);
    initMutex.unlock();
    return true;
}
```

Where `initMutex` is a private variable of the class `ManagedObject` or a global variable.

In a comment you state:

> I am not sure if a mutex will help here, since it will block the execution, not prevent it. The Initialize() method should only be ran when initialized = false

Without a mutex then it is possible for there to be multiple instances where `initialized = false`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing it like this, which works pretty well for me. It probably isn't the fastest way because of the mutex, but this is the best I could come up with right now.

```
class ManagedObject
{
protected:
  std::mutex initMutex;
  bool initialized = false;
  bool isInitializing = false;

  virtual void DoInitialize() {}

  virtual void Initialize()
  {
    if (initialized) return;

    initMutex.lock();
    if (!isInitializing)
    {
        isInitializing = true;
        DoInitialize();
        isInitializing = false;
    }
    initMutex.unlock();

    initialized = true;
  }

public:
  virtual void Invalidate()
  {
    initialized = false;
  }
}    

class Player : public ManagedObject
{
public:
  void DoInitialize()
  {
     // initialize its members here.
  }

  bool DoSomethingUseful()
  {
      Initialize();
      return true; // use some member here
  }
}
```